# Этимология слова "лошадь"

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке появилось слово "лошадь"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Слово происходит от тюркского "алаша" с тем же значением. А вот слово "конь", скорее всего, имеет кельтские корни и изначально звучало как "конек". А слово "кобыла" происходит уже от латинского caballus.

Answer (score 1):

проще надо,  кобыла от коня, если б яйца были, конем бы была. а то все латынь, да латынь.  а как до дела---коваль--от ковать. лошади уже подкованные.
лошадь от лошака, помесь коня с ослицей.некоторые утверждают от ишака--но это осел-мужик.
а тут другое.  лошак скорее всего от ложный конь  по смыслу. слова ложь-лажа-конь--получается лошак. тогда лошадь--не конь. а просто обобщение неполноценности.

Comment: а вот вам финский язык
солнце aurinko  àaurum  -латынь----золото
желтый keltainen     кельтами сегодня знаем, кого называют.      http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%E5%EB%FC%F2%FB
к китайцам ну, никакого отношения!                       
речь puhe 
язык---- kieli, kieltä             в эстонском  keelt 
заря--- aamurusko
утро—aam,aamulla, aamuna, aamuisin  вечер—illalla, illan, iltana 

вот и скажите мне откуда корешки ислама в финском языке, и откуда кельты?

Answer (score 1):

Игорь Георгиевич Добродомов, специалист по тюркизмам, утверждает, что слово "лошадь" не тюркского происхождения, а исконно русское, происходит от "лоший", то есть "плохой". Так называли коня, негодного к военному делу, но годящегося на сельскохозяйственные работы. Более подробно можно прочитать тут: http://www.svoboda.org/content/article/369157.html. Что касается слова "конь", то у Фасмера, например, про кельтов ничего не сказано.